# How do I use CKEditor's removeMenuItem() function?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to remove the 'paste' option from the right-click menu. There is a recently added function which is supposed to do this, but I'm not sure how to call it.

Documentation: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#removeMenuItem

I've tried the following in CKEditor's config.js file, which don't appear to work:

```
CKEDITOR.editor.removeMenuItem('paste');

CKEDITOR.editor.prototype.removeMenuItem('paste');

config.removeMenuItem = 'paste'; /* in main config array */
```

Any suggestions? (Removing right-click menu completely is not an option as I need it for table editing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why your tests didn't work:

```
CKEDITOR.editor.removeMenuItem('paste');
```

The CKEDITOR object doesn't have a property "editor",

```
CKEDITOR.editor.prototype.removeMenuItem('paste');
```

Ditto, and trying to get the prototype won't help.
In both cases you have some error messages waiting for you in the error console

```
config.removeMenuItem = 'paste'; /* in main config array */
```

As you have linked, removeMenuItem is a method of the editor object, not a property of the config object.

What you can do:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.removeMenuItem('paste');
```

The CKEDITOR object has a property "instances" that contains all the instances, so replace "editor" with the name of your editor and it will work. (of course, after the instance has been created, not before)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason this solution doesn't quite work with my setup. In place of 'editor' mine is 'article_body' after doing some console.log debugging. With your reasoning about ensuring the call is after the instance is created though I came up with this, which is working:

    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ck) {
      ck.editor.removeMenuItem('paste');
    });

This is the first project I'm trying to customise CKEditor properly on and I'm finding the documentation is a bit lacking in some areas. Seems to be the best WYSIWYG editor on balance at the moment though.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, it worked for me

CKEDITOR.instances.contentEditor.config.removePlugins = 'image,resize';

contentEditor is the name of the instance of CKEDITOR.

You can use the config and set removePlugins and pass a string with the name of the property, that you want to remove. But remember it will only work with those property names, that is present in the plugins object.  Like if you want to remove 'paste' you have to do this

CKEDITOR.instances.contentEditor.config.removePlugins = 'pastefromword,pastetext';

Answer (score -1):

When creating the editor in array configuration includes:
var config = {...,
                          'removeButtons': 'Maximize'};

by exzemplo

Comment: Please expand/tidy this answer, it's not very helpful in its current state.